# Silverlight RIA UsingCustomMethod not working

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

SL5 and latest RIA Services, from the XAML:

```
context.RemoveAccountFromRole(draggedPerson);
```

which gets called in the Domain Service when Invoke attribute is used:

```
 [Invoke]
 public void RemoveAccountFromRole(Account draggedPerson)
```

however when I use:

```
[Update(UsingCustomMethod = true)]
public void RemoveAccountFromRole(Account draggedPerson)
```

It never reaches the domain service when I set a breakpoint.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a DomainContext issue - I was calling from the wrong context

This is how to reference a XAML DomainContext from codebehind.

```
custDomainContext context = (custDomainContext)AccountsDataSourceT32.DomainContext;
context.RemoveAccountFromRole(draggedPerson, roleID);
AccountsDataSourceT32.SubmitChanges();
```